# How do jQueryUI tabs on click event trigger to page method, then values assign to controls in C# asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In an Aspx page, I have declared jQueryUI tabs like this:

```
<div id="tabs" style="margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 2px;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" onclick="gettabvalues(1);">Hospital</a></li>/*on click event am calling java script method through my page methods .but web methods having static key word so am not able to assign value to asp controls*/
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" onclick="gettabvalues(2);">Treatment </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// based on tab selection switch condition will execute page methods
function gettabvalues(thistab) {// parameter tab id - thistab
    switch (thistab) {
        case 1:
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'HospitalRegistrationStep2.aspx/Bindtab1',
                data: '{tabID: ' + thistab + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'HospitalRegistrationStep2.aspx/Bindtab2',
                data: '{tabID: ' + thistab + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {// Success message will throw this method.
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);// error message
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

```
 private static void Bindtab1(int tanID)
 {
       TestRetrieveRequest testRetrieveRequest =new TestRetrieveRequest();
       TestRetrieveResponse testRetrieveResponse=GetDetails(TestRetrieveRequest);
       txtAccreditation.Text = TestRetrieveResponse.TestList[0].Accreditation ;
       txtName.Text = TestRetrieveResponse.TestList[0].Name ;
       txtAGE.Text = TestRetrieveResponse.TestList[0].Age ;
       txtMobile.Text = TestRetrieveResponse.TestList[0].Mobile ;
       gvTreatment.DataSource = TestRetrieveResponse.TreatmentList;
       gvTreatment.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: inside static method am not getting asp controls ID so if u have other ways pls tel me??

Comment: your parameter on the method is called **tanID** but you are passing one called **tabID** on the ajax call.

Comment: the data property on the ajax call  remove the single quotes **data: {tabID: thistab}**